# Showing blank list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Can Help me suggesting proper format.. i was trying

```
<%DataTable dt2 = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSelectCommand("show tables", CommandType.Text); %>
        <%foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt2.Rows) {%>
        <li><%dtRow[0].ToString(); %></li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

but showint blank list with no value

Comment: Who Has Down voted me.. stupid peoples... rather then helping me

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it works

```
<%foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt2.Rows) {%>
   <%foreach(DataColumn dtCol in dt2.Columns){%>
        <li><%dtRow[dtCol].ToString(); %></li>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: thanks but replacking 3rd line with 
 <li><%Response.Write(dtRow[0].ToString()); %></li>

work fine for me..

Please Up vote my question... what is my fault ..

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesign Please edit my answer or post yours and mark as correct answer. thanks